# "Sign in with email" form of FirebaseUI doesn't appear on my screen

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

[Only saying "Welcome", no Sing-in form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KkF7.png)

[It should look like this without Google and SNS forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Uum6.png)

I'm trying to create sign-up form by FirebaseUI.

I followed the instruction to set up, but "Sign in with email" form doesn't appear on my screen.

It's just showing title "Welcome".

I already have linked my App with the Firebase project.

Xcode version - 10.2
Firebase SDK version: 5.20.2
FirebaseUI version: 6.2.1
CocoaPods Version: 1.6.1

Here's my AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

import Firebase

import FirebaseUI

@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
}
```

Viewcontroller.swift

```
 import UIKit
 import Firebase
 import FirebaseUI

 class ViewController: UIViewController, FUIAuthDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: UIButton!

var authUI: FUIAuth { get { return FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()! } }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    authUI.delegate = self
    let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = []
    authUI.providers = providers
    loginButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.loginButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func loginButtonTapped(_ : AnyObject) {
    let authViewController = authUI.authViewController()
    self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

public func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: User?, error: Error?) {
    if error == nil {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toTalkRoomTableViewController", sender: nil)
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [FUIEmailAuth()]`, and it worked just fine.